# what's relation between lock info in housekeeping data for object instance and synchronized?

Tags: java, locking, synchronized

what's the function for  lock info in housekeeping data for object instance?
if any relation related with synchronized?
Anybody know it?

Answer (score 2):

Since synchronization needs some locking mechanism and you can synchronize on any object (if you don't specify an object to use as semaphore `this` is used) you need some lock info for each object.

Answer (score 1):

The lock info in housekeeping data for an object instance is used for providing low level synchronizations. Please check out following link.

[Synchronization under the hood](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_6a.shtml)

In short, you need some place to track the information about which are the threads accessing '`this`' object and then apply the rules of synchronization on that object. The lock info in housekeeping data is that place.